# $(document) is null error when including jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, runtime, document

This is the weirdest thing I have come across. I am including jQuery as my **first** script like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I see why it isn't working, I get this error back from firbug:

```
$(document) is null
```

I don't even know where to begin with this, google came up with nothing...

Also, I know this error is related, I get this pop up box when I try to edit jQuery in FileZilla (right from server):

Script: (url)
Line: 16
Char: 1
Error: 'window' is undefined
Code: 800A1391\
Source: Microsoft JScript run time error

Comment: have you tried using a CDN version of jquery, perhaps yours is corrupted?

Comment: I tried googles before but now i've uploaded mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some other library probably steals the `$`. See if `jQuery(document)` behaves differently.

Comment: I thought that would give a different error report, like function `$` not found.. but I guess not. Thanks man.

Comment: @Phil: no, `$` is still there, it is just a different function. For exemple, Prototype sets `$` to a funtion which expects an id and returns the corresponding DOM element. Since `document` becomes something like `[object HTMLDocument]` when cast to string, and there is of course no such id, it will return null.